# AzureStaticWebApp@0 remove ALL old files before uploading new

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage, azure-static-web-app

I have an Azure Pipeline with a task using `AzureStaticWebApp@0` to push code for a static web site from an Azure Storage account.

I've noticed that there is a growing number of unused files (mostly .js webpack chuncks), is there  away of removing old files?

Maybe even deleting whole folders before pushing new code up?

The task looks a bit like this:

```
 - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
              inputs:
                app_location: 'app/dist'
                api_location: 'api'
                output_location: 'dist'
                skip_app_build: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AzureStaticWebApp@0 remove ALL old files before uploading new

You could use Azure CLI task to invoke the `az cli commands` [az storage blob delete-batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-delete-batch) to clean old files before running the `AzureStaticWebApp` task. The sample task is as below:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Visual Studio Professional Subscription(xxxxxx)'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az storage blob delete-batch -s images --account-name mystorage --source '$web' --if-unmodified-since $(date -d `"5 days ago`" ''+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ'')'
```

You could also specify `date` to delete those old file which not modified a few days ago.

You could check the document [az storage blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-delete-batch) and [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59617090/how-to-delete-files-in-azure-blob-storage-by-date-using-azurecli) for some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delete files task to clear out the contents of a folder. For example the below task would delete everything in the folder path specified

```
- task: DeleteFiles@1
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'C:/path/to/folder'
    Contents: '**/*'
```

[Delete Files Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks for that, it does not delete the files from where they are beining served - Azure Blob Store as a web app

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was staring me in the face.

Use the same `- task: AzureCLI@2` task to delete required files before uploading fresh build.
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/file?view=azure-cli-latest)